# Avoid change of a select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way of not letting users change a select input?.

I have a form with an already selected option, and I want to aware users that they are doing that and I was trying to do this.

I have a select with id=users:

```
   $("#users").change(function(){
        confirm("You are going to change the default value. Are you sure?");
   });
```

One of the problems I have is that it only happens if I click on an option, it's not happening as soon as I click on the select input.

Another thing is that it shows 2 times, is there a way of handle this?

And the last question, how can I make that after click on "cancel" button of the confirm window, it won't display the list of options and if I click on "accept" it should display the options.

I guess what I'm trying to do is a intermediate event between not doing anything and after click event on that select.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a custom interface element that looks like a select when rendered, rather than an actual select...

Comment: Well, not exactly. Just want to make people aware that they are changing an already selected option in a select input

Comment: the change event of a <select> is definitely not what you're looking for then... breaking down the UI storyboard, you want to intercept a click, display an interstitial prompt, and then conditionally open the select's dropdown based on the response to the prompt. I don't think that's a select any more...

Comment: Yes, I just tried to do that and It works but not as I want, what should I do then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's basically what Tetsujin no Oni said, but there's no reason you can't do it with a select. Just intercept a mousedown instead of a click (so it is instantaneous) and prevent the default behavior if necessary:

http://jsfiddle.net/zKHaj/5/

Also, you may want to add a boolean variable like "hasAccepted" so that you they only have to do the confirmation once.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's what I wanted but I wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: Just another question, why it works fine in that example and in my application the confirm appear 2 times? is there a way to see why is that happening?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I tried to, but couldn't replicate that behavior. I'm guessing it's because when you lose focus to display the confirm, it treats it like another change. The best way to analyze it is put some console.log calls in your change handler and see when it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the select input (either in the tag with `disabled="disabled"` or at runtime by doing)

```
$("#users").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

but then you'll want to add in either a hidden element to submit your value, or remove the disabled attribute right before you submit (otherwise the value wont get submitted.)